# Making ice from carbonated water

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Sorry if this is not the place for asking this question, but I'm going to do a real life project and don't know where else to ask.

I'm going to prepare and sell snow cones next summer. For making snow cones, I was told by ice cone makers that ice should come from carbonated water.

As in my country is quite difficult to find a proper ice factory that could produce ice with clean water, I'm planning to make my own ice for snow cones.

I was thinking to buy bottles of carbonated water, pour them in many plastic bags and freeze those bags in my refrigirator. In that way I could get carbonated ice.

My question is:

> Do you think that pouring carbonated water in plastic bags for producing ice would be a good idea? Or could I get adverse effects like water loosing sodium ?

Comment: If the carbonated water comes in plastic bottles you can freeze it directly in the bottles.

Comment: If I do that, I would have a problem taking out all the ice form the bottle.

Comment: Only if you don't want to cut the bottle. It would help also if you cool the bottles before pouring into bags. It's worth trying.

Comment: Could you define "good idea"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be no issue with putting carbonated water in plastic bags and freezing them (considering they're clean and sterile, of course). I imagine the benefit of freezing carbonated water instead of regular clean water has to do with the fact that there is much more dissolved gas in carbonated water. As the water freezes, the gas is expelled from the ice (only the water molecules will solidify), creating many pockets inside the solid ice which would weaken its structural integrity. This would likely make it much easier to shave or break into small pieces for a snow cone. I've never frozen carbonated water myself though. You should be a bit careful because as the carbonated water freezes, the carbon dioxide it releases will create pressure in a closed container, so you may end up with torn plastic bags, ruptured bottles, or a damaged freezer in the worst case.